# SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor vs SyncTaskExecutor in SpringBatch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a SpringBatch application where we are trying parallel processing. In the batch, it reads from a table and update another table with response. If there are 100 records in input table, the output table also should have 100 records.

Now, I have 13600 records in the input table. When I tried with `SyncTaskExecutor`, only one thread was running and the output table got 13600 records. When I tried with `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, there was only 900 records in the output table.

Job declaration below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd">

<import resource="applicationContext.xml" />


<bean id="itemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="select REP_QMUT_KEY, DLN_DLNRNR, DLN_AFVDAT, F_IND_MEMO_DVB, MUT_MUTDAT_UM, MUT_VERWDAT_UM, MUT_SRT_MUT_UM from REP_QMUT" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.aegon.quinto.service.mapper.MutationInputRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="simpleStep"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="itemReader" ref="itemReader" />
    <property name="itemWriter" ref="itemWriter" />
    <property name="commitInterval" value="10" />
    <property name="startLimit" value="1" />
</bean>

 <bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>
    <property name="sql" value="INSERT INTO MUT_TRIAL(DLNRNR, AFVDAT,  MEMO_MUTATION, MEMO_PARTICIPANT, MUTATION_DATE, PROCESSING_DATE, RUN_NR, SRT_MUT, REP_QMUT_CORTICON_KEY) VALUES (:dlnrnr,:afvDat,:memo,:participantMemo,:mutationDate,:processDate,:runNr,:mutationType,:mutationKey)" />
    </bean>

<bean id="simpleChunkListner" class="com.aegon.quinto.service.listener.SimpleChunkListener" />

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor" />
<bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.aegon.quinto.service.processor.SimpleItemProcessor" />

<!-- job id="simpleJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="simpleStep">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="itemReader"  writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="50">
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>

</job-->

<job id="simpleJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <step id="simpleStep">
        <tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="25">
            <chunk reader="itemReader"  processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter"
                commit-interval="50">
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>

</job>


<!--  For running the BatchLauncher -->
<bean id="batchLauncher" class="com.aegon.quinto.service.BatchLauncher">
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="job" ref="simpleJob" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

I am trying to execute the step in multiple threads

Mapper:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
```

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.aegon.quinto.model.MutationInput;

public class MutationInputRowMapper implements RowMapper {

```
public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MutationInput mutationInput = new MutationInput();
    mutationInput.setMutationKey(rs.getInt("REP_QMUT_KEY"));
    mutationInput.setDlnrnr(rs.getString("DLN_DLNRNR"));
    mutationInput.setMemo(rs.getString("F_IND_MEMO_MVM"));
    mutationInput.setParticipantMemo(rs.getString("F_IND_MEMO_DVB"));
    mutationInput.setProcessDate(rs.getInt("MUT_VERWDAT_UM"));
    mutationInput.setRunNr(new Integer("2"));
    mutationInput.setMutationType(rs.getString("MUT_SRT_MUT_UM"));

    return mutationInput;
}
```

}

My overall requirement is as follows:
I will read data from an input table, validate the data with an external service and update the validation response in an output table.In the input table, data will be in flat structure. i.e, For a student there could be exam results for multiple exams. I need to retrieve all the exam results for that participant before going to the external service.
Communicating with the external service would be a bottleneck due to network latency. Hence, multi-threading is needed.
If there are any sample implementations / any guide, please show me the way.
P.S: I am a newbie to SpringBatch.

Comment: Add your taskExecutor's config too.

Comment: TaskExecutor's config is at the first line of the code

Comment: @Rajkumar When you say only 900 records were written when using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor, was the Job status COMPLETED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like one or more of your components is not threadsafe

Comment: I am using `JdbcCursorItemReader` and `JdbcBatchItemWriter` for reading and writing. Should I use some other readers?

Comment: there are more components, the itemProcessor and the used data object between reader, processor and writer, pls post them all :-)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Added the entire xml above.

Comment: why are there 2 simpleStep configurations? can add the sources too? especially your own code from mapper and processor